# User ID in Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I use AWS API Gateway + AWS Cognito (Federated Identity + User Pool). I'm creating REST API in API Gateway. There are methods for getting users list and for getting user by id. What should I use as user ID?

Response should contain te following user data: ID, username, first name, last name etc. Username, first name, last name are stored in User Pool attributes.

I see in [examples](https://github.com/AnomalyInnovations/serverless-stack-demo-api/blob/master/create.js) that they use cognitoIdentityId as User ID. If I will  use cognitoIdentityId as ID, then how should I get user data by this ID? Please give me an example or link to API reference how to get user data by cognitoIdentityId.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get user attributes as shown in the following example using the Username.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1'; //This is required to derive the endpoint
var poolData = { UserPoolId : 'us-east-1_TcoKGbf7n',
    ClientId : '4pe2usejqcdmhi0a25jp4b5sh3'
};
var userPool = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
var userData = { 
                Username : 'username',
                Pool : userPool
            };
var cognitoUser = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);

cognitoUser.getUserAttributes(function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        alert(err);
        return;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        console.log('attribute ' + result[i].getName() + ' has value ' + result[i].getValue());
    }
});
```

Reference: [Examples: Using the JavaScript SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html)

If you need to query the user attributes using AccessToken, then use the following example.

```
var params = {
  AccessToken: 'STRING_VALUE' /* required */
};
cognitoidentityserviceprovider.getUser(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Reference: [AWS JavaScript SDK GetUser](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#getUser-property)

Note: Currently there is no support in both AWS JavaScript SDK and API to get the user attributes by UserId.

Comment: I need to get User Attributes in lambda function in backend. There is no username, I have only user ID in backend.

Comment: Currently there is no support in both AWS JavaScript SDK and API to get the user attributes by UserId. You need to either store the Username or use the id token, returned from AWS Cognito Userpools authentication to query the user attributes.

Comment: I just want to get user by id. It is strange that Cognito does not allow it